# How to show a progress bar while Firebase data loads

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to show a progress bar while data from Javascript loads to the website.

```
  paperRef.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      numberOfPapers = snapshot.numChildren();
  });
```

How to show a progress bar till numberOfPapers gets counted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `once()` method is asynchronous and returns a promise.

As explained in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

> A Promise is in one of these states:
>
> - pending: initial state, neither fulfilled nor rejected.
> - fulfilled: meaning that the operation completed successfully.
> - rejected: meaning that the operation failed.

You need to show a progress bar just before you call the `once()` method and hide it either if the promise is fulfilled or rejected. For that you will use the [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) and [`catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) methods, as follows:

```
  showProgressBar();
  paperRef.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      //Promise is fulfilled
      hideProgressBar();
      numberOfPapers = snapshot.numChildren();
  })
  .catch(error => {
      //Promise is rejected
      hideProgressBar();
      //Show an error message
  });
```

Since you didn't give any detail on which kind of progress bar you plan to use, it's up to you to implement the `showProgressBar()` and `hideProgressBar()` methods (showing/hiding a div, a spinner image, etc...)